# Difference Between STSDEV and VSeWSS 1.3 Projects

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

Some time back, I created two separate SharePoint projects in VS 2008; one using STSDEV, the other using VSeWSS 3.0. I want both of these projects to be created with VS extensions, but how can I tell them apart? The project files look very similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output in both seems to be the same so the simple answer seems to be re-create both in VSeWSS 1.3

Answer (score 0):

Inside the .csproj file (or .vbproj, heaven-forbid) you'll find a `<ProjectGuids>` tag or something very similar. Their should be a guid in that element unique to each project type.

-Oisin

Comment: But how do I tell if it was created with VSeWSS or STSDEV?

Comment: If you create a project yourself using STSDEV (or VSeWSS) and examine the csproj/vbproj it makes, you will be able to tell, no? I figured that part was obvious, sorry.